# OAuth2 token, message: '{ “error” : “access_denied” }' returned when I try to connect to Google Calendar using OAuth

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Standard Library for ASP.NET for using Calendar Service Version 3 and I have set up a Service Account type for OAuth 2.0 Authentication through Google API Console.
Now My name Objective is to connect the calendar using OAuth2. As it is working fine for most of the user but getting problem for some limited user as they are getting error=access_denied.
I am getting authenticated from OAuth 2 by using below code

```
 private static string PrivateFeed = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";    
public static string GenerateGoogleOAuthURL(String ReturnUrl)
{
    string Url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type={2}&client_id={3}&state={4}&access_type={5}&approval_prompt={6}";
    string scope = UrlEncodeForGoogle(PrivateFeed).Replace("%20", "+");
    string redirect_uri_encode = UrlEncodeForGoogle(ReturnUrl);
    string response_type = "code";
    string state = "";
    string access_type = "offline";
    string approval_prompt = "force";        
    String ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"].ToString();
    return string.Format(Url, scope, redirect_uri_encode, response_type, ClientID, state, access_type, approval_prompt);
}
```

and while return back to the redirect page i am getting an refresh token using below code :-

```
 private String ExchangeCodeWithAccessAndRefreshToken()
{
    string Url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    string grant_type = "authorization_code";
    string redirect_uri_encode = string.Empty;
    redirect_uri_encode = UrlEncodeForGoogle(Convert.ToString(Session["URL"]));     
    string data = "code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type={4}";
    string Code = Request.QueryString["Code"];
    String ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"].ToString();
    String ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"].ToString();
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = string.Empty;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string param = string.Format(data, Code, ClientID, ClientSecret, redirect_uri_encode, grant_type);
        var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var tokenData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<GoogleTokenModel>(result);
            return tokenData.Refresh_Token;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I think as i have specified the state as blank. Might be i have to specify some value here. am i right?

Comment: No. The state parameter is merely a convenience for you to pass information from your service to your oauthcallback. It has no effect on the authorization process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you able to detect any problem in my code. The main thing is that it is working for 90% of my client only 10 % are creating problem.

Comment: if it works for 90% then the problem is probably not in the code that you posted. It could be a problem with the stored refresh token for the 10%.

Comment: I am getting the problem at the time of connection with calendar means while authentication only. i am storing all the refresh token in DB after getting the refresh token from above process.

Comment: Please comment on this issue i am still getting this problem. I am really confused how can other user are able to connect and disconnect with my application.